# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 4

Tags: forms, laravel

Form open section

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@register')) }}
```

my HomeController

```
public function register()
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->house = Input::get('house');
    $user->phone = Input::get('phone');
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->last_name = Input::get('last_name');

    $user-> save();
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/register','HomeController@showRegister');
Route::get('/home/register','HomeController@register');
```

the form is showing correctly but when i submit the form i got this error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Answer (score 1):

MethodNotAllowedHttpException means that the route is good but the method is wrong.

You must create it as a POST route:

```
Route::post('/home/register','HomeController@register');
```